# get the id of custom post type in single page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type in my wordpress template named **downloads**.

The problem is I can't get the id of post with this type in single page using these codes

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

But I can get the id of posts with type page or post with that lines.

How can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried: echo `global $post; var_dump($post);` … What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer of my question.

When I register post type with `register_post_type()` method I should use `flush_rewrite_rules()` to recreate url rewrites rules after that.

This problem occured because the url rewrite rules cause I can't get post content and so post id in `single.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio');

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_ID();
endwhile;
```